# Permanent magnet alternator: what happens when windings get shorted together for voltage regulation?

Tags: voltage-regulator, electromagnetism, generator, shunt, alternator

Here is a typical scheme for a permanent magnet 3 phase alternator as found on many motorcycles and recreational vehicles, with rectification to DC via a diode bridge and subsequent voltage regulation done by a shunting regulator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/prQwz.png

Mechanically, it is a fixed stator with 18 coils wound on a core, around which rotates a flywheel with magnets, which is attached directly to the crankshaft. The RPM range of this particular engine is 1500 - 7500.

As I think about it, the system has 2 opposite conditions - the load is zero, there's no current in the coils, and the essentially open circuit stator at high RPM can produce tens of volts AC, we are taking easily over 50 V AC.

The voltage required to run and charge a DC system would be around 14.5 V.

This means that when the alternator outputs over the threshold voltage (plus voltage drop from the diode bridge) the regulator opens the SCR's (or are they TRIAC's) and shunts all 3 windings together.

So we come to the other extreme - an essentially infinite load - a short circuit.

Here's what I can't understand - say at some high RPM's where the alternator is rated for its maximum current we work continously in the shunting regime.

Apparently, it would induce a current circulating in the coils to create a magnetic field opposing the field from the rotating flywheel.

What would the voltage and current within the windings be limited by? As an extension, would the stator coils be heated by the power generated from it, using V * I?

How will it compare if now, instead of shunting the "excess power", an external load is switched on such that it is exactly equal to the alternator's output?

In this scenario, I'm assuming the regulator never kicks in and only the diode bridge is "fully loaded".

---

A way to rephrase the question would be:

In which of the 2 scenarios will there be LESS heat produced in the stator coils (at the RPM where its rated for maximum power):
When it is fully loaded so that no shunting occurs?

When there's minimal external load and stator coils are always in "shunt mode"?

---

Quick bonus question please:

I've got 2 sets of flywheel + stator combos, from the same engine but different years, one in which the system is rated at 280 W, one with 400 W.

Apparently, their magnets are different, I couldn't yet check it [EDIT: checked and magnets are somewhat stronger]

The stators look very similar, so I tried to connect a power supply across the phases and passed a current between 5-10 A through each phase for both stators and recorded the voltage drop in the coils.

By dividing the 2 numbers i got some value which to me seems like it's resistance (i don't have good knowledge of reactance, inductance etc...apologies for that).

I'm surprised at the results.

The coils from 280 W stator gave 0.27 Ohms.
From 400 W stator gave 0.36 Ohms.

Does this make sense?
I would've thought the "more powerful stator" would have less "resistance"?
What do you reckon would happen to alternator output and longevity if they were to be run mis-matched, in other words what do you think is the deciding factor here in providing the increased alternator output?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this kind of circuit, but shunting a coil in an alternator will create a braking tourque on the rotor, with equivalent braking power to the resistive loss of the coil. The electrical power loss of the coil would be maximal in this case.  The elements in the circuit are thyristors/SCRs, not TRIACs.